# Non-4-inch apps top-aligned when new splash included

Tags: iphone, ios, retina-display, splash-screen

Apple is now requiring a retina and 4-inch display Splash page (i.e. the "Default-568h@2x.png") for all apps to be submitted, which is fine.  However, when I include that and then do another build, once I get into the app, instead of it being centered with dark on the top and bottom (as it was before), is now top-aligned on the screen with 2x the blank space on the bottom.. which looks really unprofessional.

Is there any way via our configuration to tell the OS to go back to centering the app, despite that it has the now-required 4" Splash page included?  Ideally I'd like to be able to do this without updating every single IB view in the app to center it manually, as I feel the OS should still be able to do this somehow via configuration.

FYI, answers that say "update your entire app for 4"!" are unacceptable.  There are clients who don't yet have a creative budget for this but still want to keep their existing app looking decent in the store.  If it's not possible, then it's not possible, but that is why I'm asking the question.

Thanks in advance for any assistance on this, and my apologies if this has already been asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to do what you're asking with a single setting. Your best options are a bit of code that runs when you load a view to change the `origin.y` position, or, go through the XIB files and update the autoresizing rules so that the views expand to fill the space. You might not have budget to update the graphics resources in the app but you should be able to spend the small amount of time required on autoresizing.

The caveat to 'small amount of time' may apply to you - if you explicitly set the size of all of your views in code you've made life painful for yourself.

Comment: Yep, looks like I misunderstood the requirement from Apple, and I was hoping there was a configuration change that could re-apply what they were doing before.  Oh well, it is what it is.. This applies to multiple apps I am submitting for clients, some of which I built and some not.  It will be headache for some, and fairly straight-forward for others.  Thanks for the response and suggestion on how to resolve.  Marking as the accepted answer for that.

Answer (score 2):

As of May 1 if your submitting this app to the app store you will be required to support both retina display's, and the new 4" screen size.

https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=3212013b

Comment: Yep, I got the memo on it, but I guess I simply mis-understood the requirement.  Thanks for the link, tho.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand. As of now, you must fully support the full 4" screen of the iPhone 5 and 5th gen iPod touch, in addition to retina and non-retina devices.

By adding the "Default-568h@2x.png" launch image (it is not a splash screen) you are telling the OS that your app supports the 4" screen.

You must update your app to fill the screen. There are countless existing posts about how to do that. There is no way around this. It is 100% required - no exception from Apple.

BTW - Apple announced this requirement on March 21st. Every registered iOS developer was notified of the requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Please note that I was not arguing the point or complaining about it, nor even implying there are no posts about how to update apps to work for retina, but rather just asking the question if it's possible.  And FYI, I know many iOS developers who have been doing this since the beginning (myself included) who use the terminology of "Splash Screen" to refer to the loading image.  It's just my terminology. :)  Regardless, I appreciate you taking the time to respond.

Comment: Sorry if my post has the wrong tone to it. I didn't mean to sound the way it came out. I intended to point out facts. Good luck with the clients.

Comment: So worries at all; you're correct in what you say, as I misunderstood the requirement from Apple.  It's ultimately a good thing, since it will force clients to find the creative budget to update their apps.  Thanks again, and take care.